# Need to implement custom filtering logic for DataXGrid from MUI react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

My DataGrid implementation from MUI react uses the following data:

```
const percentageComparator: GridComparatorFn<PercentageTendencyProps> = (
  pt1,
  pt2
) => {
  return pt1.percentage - pt2.percentage
}
const columns = [{
        field: 'percentage',
        headerName: '%',
        width: 150,
        valueGetter:(params: GridValueGetterParams) => {
         return params.row.percentage.value + "%" + params.row.percentage.tendency
        }
        sortComparator: percentageComparator,
        filterOperators: getGridNumericOperators(),
      },
       {
        field: 'goal',
        width: 150,
        filterOperators: getGridNumericOperators(),
      },
]
const rows = [
{
  id: 0, percentage: {value: 10, tendency: 'down'}, goal: 10
}, {
id: 1, percentage: {value: 10, tendency: 'down'}, goal: 10
}, {
id: 2, percentage: {value: 10, tendency: 'down'}, goal: 10
}
]
```

as you can see, sorting can be customised and I could use a custom comparator function, but I also need to customise the filtering and access the value property inside percentage object.

Any suggestions on how to do that? Is there a function that could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Old thread I know, but is this perhaps what you were after?
You request a child of an object with the "." operator.

return pt1.percentage.value - pt2.percentage.value